# Fix Music.app metadata from cloud?

Tags: music, apple-music, music.app

Many of the songs in my Apple Music Library have inconsistent metadata (years missing, titles misspelled, etc.) This is weird, because it was once all correct. I suspect that Apple hasn't migrated my music properly over the years.

Is there any way to "fix" the metadata by going to cloud databases?

Comment: I have a large music library but it’s from my personal collection of vinyl and CDs.  When I imported things into iTunes/Apple Music, I found a lot of the metadata incorrect (especially cover art!). Is this Music yours as in you paid for it or is it the music you are entitled to access via the service?  If it’s yours then you can use a tool like [Music Brainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/) to clean up and organize your Library

Comment: @Allan -   Neat. It's my own music. Please make this an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

An excellent tool that I’ve used to manage my music collection is [Music Brainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/).  It’s a cross-platform FOSS (Free Open Source Software) that automates the metadata management of your library.

My suggestion when using this is to make a small batch to test out with.  There are TONS of options including the ability to script how things are handled including the naming of the file and how they are stored (by album, artist, genere, etc.).  You don’t want to do this on your whole library until you get your workflow correct.

I made a backup of my entire library, started with a blank slate, then then ran my music through Music Brainz to download the metadata and album art so that the “new” library would be nice and organized to my specefications.

One of the most powerful features is the AcousticID that will digitally match the fingerprint of your music to the correct metadata.

I also suggest that you create a [Music Brainz](https://musicbrainz.org/) account (not required to utilize the software), to directly access the database.  It’s the same one that Scrobblers like LastFM use to identify tracks.  The benefit to having this is if the AcousticID is not correct or non-existant, you can submit your music fingerprint to the database for future recognition.